# jQuery - 'href' plug-in?

Tags: javascript, jquery

if anyone knows is plug-in who can find links on div and make clickable? I have div with text:

```
<div id="mytext">Wow, please go to http://www.google.com - this is my home page ;)</div>
```

And I want make automatic clickable links.

Comment: this is actually interesting, I'm pretty sure you won't find a plugin out there, but you can make a function that does that

Comment: Use `replace` and the search bar to look for a regex.

Comment: I don't know one, SO [does however](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37684/how-to-replace-plain-urls-with-links). Gotta love searching...

Comment: See [jquery's linkify](http://soapbox.github.io/jQuery-linkify/). Better than reinventing the wheel because there are a million edge cases unless you only intend to work on a specific subset of data.

Answer (score 0):

An easy to follow implementation:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tomanow/z5Uz5/1/)

```
var url_pattern = /((([A-Za-z]{3,9}:(?:\/\/)?)(?:[\-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)?[A-Za-z0-9\.\-]+|(?:www\.|[\-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)[A-Za-z0-9\.\-]+)((?:\/[\+~%\/\.\w\-_]*)?\??(?:[\-\+=&;%@\.\w_]*)#?(?:[\.\!\/\\\w]*))?)/;

var content = $("#mytext").text();
var newContent = content.replace(url_pattern, function (link) {
    return '<a href="' + link + '" target="_blank">' + link + '</a>';
});
$('#mytext').html(newContent);
```